# DirectX 11 Object flickering by rotating

Tags: c++, directx-11

The problem is if I rotate the Triangle and the rotation is over 1.6f it starts to flickering.

[image: example]

Here is a piece of code:

-here is a small setting which is initalized in the renderer

```
mCamPosition = D3DXVECTOR3{ 0.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f };
mCamTarget = D3DXVECTOR3{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
mCamUp = D3DXVECTOR3{ 0.0f, 1.0f,0.0f };

D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&mCamView, &mCamPosition, &mCamTarget, &mCamUp);
D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&mCamProjection, 0.4f * static_cast<float32>(M_PI),
    static_cast<float32>(pWindow->GetSize().Width) / static_cast<float32>(pWindow->GetSize().Height),
    1.0f,
    1000.0f);
```

-part of the main loop

```
...
rotation += 0.0005f;
MeshTransform.SetRotation(rotation);

Renderer->Clear();
Renderer->Draw(Mesh, Shader, &MeshTransform);
Renderer->Display();
...
```

-part of the draw function

```
D3DXMATRIX MeshTranslation;
D3DXMATRIX MeshRotaiton;
D3DXMATRIX MeshWorld;

D3DXMatrixIdentity(&MeshWorld);
D3DXMatrixIdentity(&MeshRotaiton);
D3DXMatrixIdentity(&MeshTranslation);

//Translation
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&MeshTranslation, pTransform->mPosition.X, pTransform->mPosition.Y, 0.0f);


//Rotation
D3DXVECTOR3 RotAxis{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&MeshRotaiton, &RotAxis, pTransform->mRotation);


MeshWorld = MeshRotaiton * MeshTranslation;


mWVP = MeshWorld * mCamView * mCamProjection;
D3DXMatrixTranspose(&mCBPerObject.WVP, &mWVP);

pContext->DeviceContext->UpdateSubresource(pPerObjectBuffer, NULL, nullptr, &mCBPerObject, NULL, NULL);
pContext->DeviceContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &pPerObjectBuffer);


pContext->DeviceContext->VSSetShader(pShader->cpVertexShader.Get(), 0, 0);
pContext->DeviceContext->PSSetShader(pShader->cpPixelShader.Get(), 0, 0);
...Drawing
```

-Shader file

```
cbuffer cbPerObject
{
    float4x4 WVP;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

VS_OUTPUT VS(float4 InPosition : POSITION, float4 InColor : COLOR)
{
    VS_OUTPUT Output;

    Output.Position = mul(InPosition, WVP);
    Output.Color = InColor;

    return Output;
}

float4 PS(VS_OUTPUT Input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return Input.Color;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your near plane of projection matrix ... Try a Lower 
value for near plane.

Comment: I tried it with a higher value and it didnt work than I tried a lower value it worked thank you !